# Analog values to ppm

Tags: analog, temperature, units

How to transform a set of analog voltages from voltage to ppm/K?

I have to use this to calculate the temperature coefficient of a bandgap.

Is the derivative the same as the temperature coefficient calculated in ppm/K?

[image]

The derivative of the function:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. Think about it.

Comment: How would you show the behavior of that bandgap circuit? I would plot ... as a function of ... Then I could choose a certain point in that plot and determine the derivative at that point. What would be the unit of that number? What does 1 ppm actually mean?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I added the results.

Comment: That is indeed the plot I would make. Still 2 of my questions to you remain unanswered.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I added also the derivative of the function. The unit is milli? Is there a formula that links the milli and the ppm?

Comment: You're asking me if a unit is milli? Do you think Mega and micro are units as well? What does milli mean? Go read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Comment: It was a mistake with the question mark. It was not intended to be a question but a statement.

Comment: Still, milli is not a unit.

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate the derivative, the resulting units are the units of y divided by the units of x. So here, it would be \$V/K\$ (deg C and K are the same unit when considered differentially). If you divide the derivative by the typical/nominal voltage, the resulting units are then just \$1/K\$. The values will be fairly small, so you often use a unitless scale factor like ppm. Unitless scale factors are not really part of the SI system of units (as far as I know), but they are a common convention.

You are dealing here with unitless scale factors. The most common example of a unitless scale factor is %, meaning \$10^{-2}\$.

Your second plot shows a scale factor of "milli", meaning \$10^{-3}\$. I'm not sure if you have already divided by the nominal voltage or not. This is a fairly unusual scale factor when not combined with a base unit, but it's still done at times.

**You can convert milli to ppm by multiplying by 1000**, since ppm means parts per million, \$1/1000000\$ = \$10^{-6}\$, which is 1000 times smaller than \$1/1000\$.

So a value of "0.4 milli" is the same as "400 ppm". Just make sure you are actually dealing with "milli"/K, first, not millivolts/K.

Answer (score 1):

> How to transform a set of analog voltages from V to ppm/K?

The basic way is to take your 1st graph and draw red lines on it like I have: -

[image]

The red diagonal line represents the average slope between -40 °C and +125 °C. I've also added horizontal and vertical lines that you can use to pick-off the numbers.

So, the voltage changes 10 mV in a temperature range of 96 °C. That's approximately 102 μV per °C. Given that your mid range average is about 1.195 volts, that 102 μV is, in terms of parts per million, this: -

$$\dfrac{102}{1.195} = 85.4$$

So, the average drift of your voltage is 85.4 ppm/°C or 85.4 ppm/K

> Is the derivative the same as the temperature coefficient calculated
>   in ppm/K?

I think you can answer this yourself armed with the above.